# Влияния пустых игровых объекторв (Create -> Empty) на производительность мобильной игры

Tags: unity3d

Интересует следующий вопрос: Для удобства разделения объектов в иерархии я создал несколько пустых игровых объектов (Create -> Empty) и назвал их: Player settings, Enemy settings и так далее. Подскажите, насколько эти пустые объекты влияют на производительность и не лучше ли мне их убрать? Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Объект, с вложениями, лишь с годен для группировок, чтобы отделить логику и представление, что внутри в этих группах. Обычно это нужно, для создания пулов или иерархий которые будут использоваться в дальнейшем в сцене или в коде. На производительность пустой объект не влияет, но стоит заметить, что любой объект будет выделять память, не выделяет только выключенный объект. Пустой объект, без рендера не несет никакой нагрузки на `GPU`, но все-же занимает время `CPU` хоть и незначительное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не влияет (если они действительно пустые и ничего с ними не делается в каком-нибудь месте кода). Можете скриптом создать скажем 10000 пустых объектов и сравнить FPS, он не изменится.